# Get all installed applications along with Settings,Messages,Camera/ Only those app visible in Applications menu

Tags: android

I am trying to get a List of all applications which include all Installed Application and few System applications like Camera,Settings,Messages. I got all user installed by using

`ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM == 0`

and all System Applications by 
   `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM == 1`  ,
also got few system apps from
   `ApplictionInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP`  but not all

But i want to get all applications which I see in applications section of my phone,
So can anyone help me how I can filter out System Applications to get only Camera ,Settings , Messages etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code,

```
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
    {
       String str = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString() + "\n";
       ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
       results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
       Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
       icon =  rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    }
```

Comment: simply awesome,,thanks a lot :) it worked ,,.and thanks fr quick help